# How can I fill color to extracted text?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
itemmaintit = Label(addedFrame1.inner, anchor="w", text=tit0.value, width=95, height=2, font=('HCR Batang', 16), background="blue", border=0)
itemmaintit.config(cursor='arrow')
itemmaintit.pack(pady=(0,20))
itemmaintit[0:9] = Label(fg="red")
```

If `itemmaintit[0:9]` is "abcdeeffg" how to apply fill color? The above code is my practice.

```
test = itemmaintit[0:9]
test.config(fg="blue")
```

has also failed.

Comment: That is not how it works, I don't understand why You expected it to work since in this case it is not even logical, either how, You have to use either `Text` widget and then use tags or create two `Labels`, one for one color text, the other for other color text (but using `Text` will probably be easier) here are some [docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text.html)

Comment: i cannot help using two Labels because to fill either color. thank you I will see docs.

Answer (score 0):

A label can only ever have a single background color and a single foreground color. If you want to color individual characters you either need to join multiple labels together, or use a widget more suited to colorizing individual characters such as a `Text` widget.